# Compiling java files using gwt and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I pretty know nothing about GWT and Java. Following the docs, I tried to compile Java files from a web project that had been precedently developed using GWT. I installed the right plugins using the recommended IDE Eclipse. When running the compiler using the command GWT Compile, I had this message error :

```
6 juil. 2012 18:21:32 
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:155)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.SourceFileCompilationUnit.asCachedCompilationUnit(SourceFileCompilationUnit.java:59)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationUnit.writeReplace(CompilationUnit.java:392)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: it would be better if you could post the whole stacktrace, as you can see one of the messages says "See the nested exceptions for details"

Comment: I compiled it again and I ha ve a new message : java.org.primagora
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.client.primagoraEntryPoint'
         [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'org.client.primagoraEntryPoint' is really what you meant
         [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
Exception in thread "UnitWriteThread" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: and then the following :   at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:155)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.SourceFileCompilationUnit.asCachedCompilationUnit(SourceFileCompilationUnit.java:59)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationUnit.writeReplace(CompilationUnit.java:392)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Comment: it's better to add that info in the question itself, you should have the option to edit your question and format it as source code so it can be easily read.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know you can do that

Comment: Oh sorry I realize I lost the formatting of your edit :\)

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to compile?

Comment: Thanks for your response but I had in fact two problems I finally solved : library missing and incorrect path for the files I imported into eclipse

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus is part of JDO. It's very possible that this is an appengine project that you're trying to compile.

Comment: I don't really know..., what can I do to debugg ?

Comment: Does the project have a build file, either ant or maven?

Comment: I didin't find it. I know I installed ant. Where am I supposed to find this file ?

Comment: In the root of your project... you might want to also go in eclipse to Project | Properties | Builders and look to see how the project is being built. My guess is that the project you imported had an eclipse config already in it.

Comment: I went to the location you indicated and I found "Java Builder", "Faceted Project Validation Builder", "Enhancer", "Google App Engine Project Validator", "Google App Engine Change Notifier", "Google App Toolkit Project Validator", "Google WebApp Project" Validator"

Comment: Yeah, so it's an appengine project. You need to read up on the appengine documentation to understand how it's being built.